# I want to style header in my react app, but there is an error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web

This is the error:

```
Type '{ children: Element[]; style: { backgroundColor: string; }; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & { children: ReactNode; }'.
  Property 'style' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & { children: ReactNode; }'.ts(2322)
```

This is the code

```
import Head from "next/head";

export default function Home() {
    return (
        <div>
            <Head ***style***={{backgroundColor: "#FCECD5"}}>
                <title>Eatsie</title>
                <meta name="description" content="A lovely app for lovely people" />
                <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
            </Head>

            <main className="container mx-auto flex items-center justify-center">
                <div className="h-screen">Hello world!</div>
            </main>
        </div>
    );
}
```

The "style" is red underlined

I tried to change the background color of the header tag but its not working

Answer (score 2):

The nextjs `Head` is the HTML's corresponding `<head>` tag.
It's used to handle metadata, links to stylesheets, and information about device resolutions.

So it doesn't really make sense to add any styles to this element.

If you want to add any styles add them inside the  `main` content